# Is there any API in NatTable examples which shows source code upon clicking view source link?

Tags: nattable

I just wanted to know how View Source link is working which opens source code of a particular example NatTable class upon clicking. Same kind of requirement is there. So just wanted to know whether is there any built in API which fetches source code of a class.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such open source API. For the examples we simply include the sources in the examples jar file and have a mechanism that loads the .java file from the jar and opens it in a new Shell.

Comment: Thank you Dirk Fauth for quick response. Is that mechanism is available in the example jar ?

Comment: That is what I have written in the answer.